# time format using helper method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have time data filed in my table

```
t.time "start_time"
t.time "end_time"
```

and when I add the data it displays in this format

```
Start Time  2000-01-01 06:00:00 UTC
End Time    2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC
```

I want only time to be displayed? How do I do that.?

my form is like this

```
      <div class="form-group row">
         <%= form.label :start_date, class: "control-label text-right col-md-2" %>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="input-group">
             <%= form.text_field :start_date, id: :course_start_date, value: "#{format_date(form.object.start_date)}", class: "form-control mydatepicker" %>
             <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <%= form.label :end_date, class: "control-label text-right col-md-2" %>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="input-group">
              <%= form.text_field :end_date, id: :course_end_date, value: "#{format_date(form.object.end_date)}", class:"form-control mydatepicker" %>
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to achieve this.

`date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: <%=  @course.end_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') %> this is solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to 
`strftime("%I:%M%p")`
And for more information look [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Answer (score 0):

Use code below it will solve your issue :

```
Time.parse(start_time).strftime("%H:%M")
```

Comment: where should I add this? should I define a method for this in the model or what?  I am new to this so I am asking.it might be silly question

Comment: you can write in view itself .

Answer (score 0):

Rails has the [`to_formatted_s`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) helper method (which is aliased to `to_s`. This helper method has several date and time formats already defined and it is easy to define own formats.

You are lucky because returning just the time without date information already exists:

```
start_date.to_s(:time)
```

The benefits of using named date and time formats in Rails over using `strftime` directly are that it makes it much easier to change formats later on because there is only one place to change. And that you can define formats that are depending on a locale.